# Django dynamic name values in model overview on admin site

Tags: python, django

What i try to archive is having dynamic information about models, like the count, on the default admin view page where all the registered models are listed.

I do it now in an extremely hackish way, like:

```
class x(object):
    def __unicode__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return u"Items (%i items)" % SteamItem.objects.count()
class Item(models.Model)
    ...
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = x()
```

**Is there a way to do the same in a nicer way without having to edit the admin template ?**
If editing the admin template is the only way I'd appreciate some hints where to start my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introspecting the [django admin code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/contrib/admin/sites/#AdminSite.index) I found out that unfortunately the model class is not being passed to the template context - so you cannot easily query for object count. What is passed to the template for every model is:

```
model_dict = {
    'name': capfirst(model._meta.verbose_name_plural),
    'object_name': model._meta.object_name,
    'perms': perms,
}
```

What you could do is override `AdminSite._build_app_dict` to include the model class itself, override the default index template and the just query in the template using:

```
{{ model_class.objects.count }}
```

The default template is `admin/index.html` but can be configured on per admin site basis as you can see in the above mentioned class.